# where is CollectionExtensions.ObserveCollectionChanged() within ReactiveUI 4.0.2?

Tags: reactiveui

ReactiveUI 3.2.0.0 used to have CollectionExtensions class that implemented ObserveCollectionChanged() method. Where is the method now under ReactiveUI 4.0.2?

```
    private readonly ReactiveCollection<string> _sourceItems = new ReactiveCollection<string>();
    private readonly ReactiveCollection<SelectableDataItem<string>> _selectableItemsView = null;
    private readonly ReactiveCollection<SelectableDataItem<string>> _selectedItemsView = null;
    private readonly ReactiveCollection<string> _selectedDataView = null;

    ....


        this._sourceItems.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;

        this._selectableItemsView =
            this.SourceItems.CreateDerivedCollection<string, SelectableDataItem<string>>(i => new SelectableDataItem<string>(i) { IsSelected = true, });
        this._selectableItemsView.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;
        this._selectedItemsView =
            this._selectableItemsView.CreateDerivedCollection<SelectableDataItem<string>, SelectableDataItem<string>>(
            i => i,
            f => f.IsSelected,
            (i1, i2) => 0
            );
        this._selectedItemsView.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;
        this._selectedDataView =
            this._selectableItemsView.CreateDerivedCollection<SelectableDataItem<string>, string>(i => i.Data, f => f.IsSelected, (i1, i2) => 0);
        this._selectedDataView.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;
```

Comment: ReactiveUI's `ReactiveCollection` class no longer inherits from .NET's `ObservableCollection`. What goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was planning to upgrade ReactiveUI 3.2 to 4.0.2 and I have A ReactiveCollectionView type implemented which is read-only, filterable, and sortable wrapper around a ReactiveCollection. The view relies on ObserveCollectionChanged() to get a notification from the wrapped collection about NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset so the wrapper can refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to ReactiveUI 4.1, and use `someCollection.CreateDerivedCollection` - all of the work has been done for you already :)

Comment: Paul, thank you very much for the help.  I'll try it out tonight. Is CreateDerivedCollection(...) capable of producing a read-only wrapper? Is there any conceptual review document describing this cool an powerful framework?

Comment: Ok, I did upgrade to v4.1 and using CreateDerivedCollection(...) to produce derived reactive collections. One thing, I noticed,  is it seems that the source collections ItemChanged does not get triggered, hence any change/update of an item within source collection are not reflected within the derived one. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? BTW, adding items to the source is reflected within the derivative.

Comment: @AKornich ItemChanged only fires if you have ChangeTrackingEnabled set to true

Comment: Paul, thanks! However, it does not seem to help. Here is my code snippet:<pre><code>                      private readonly ReactiveCollection<string> _sourceItems = new ReactiveCollection<string>();
        private readonly ReactiveCollection<SelectableDataItem<string>> _selectableItemsView = null;
        private readonly ReactiveCollection<SelectableDataItem<string>> _selectedItemsView = null;
        private readonly ReactiveCollection<string> _selectedDataView = null;

Comment: this._sourceItems.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;

            this._selectableItemsView =
                this.SourceItems.CreateDerivedCollection<string, SelectableDataItem<string>>(i => new SelectableDataItem<string>(i) { IsSelected = true, });
            this._selectableItemsView.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;

Comment: this._selectedItemsView =
                this._selectableItemsView.CreateDerivedCollection<SelectableDataItem<string>, SelectableDataItem<string>>(
                i => i,
                f => f.IsSelected,
                (i1, i2) => 0
                );
            this._selectedItemsView.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;

Comment: this._selectedDataView =
                this._selectableItemsView.CreateDerivedCollection<SelectableDataItem<string>, string>(i => i.Data, f => f.IsSelected, (i1, i2) => 0);
            this._selectedDataView.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;

Comment: sorry, I could not figure out how to format code in the comments. I just added it formatted to the original question...